# Loop to check if TextBoxes are not empty

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I try to `For` loop through all controls on a form to check if a TextBox is empty. Then puts focus on the first empty TextBox.

My Excel VBA Form has 34 TextBox. For now it has a nested `If` function that checks if all TextBoxes are not empty. If there are any empty `.SetFocus` on the 1st empty TextBox.

```
Sub ValidateForm()
  If TextBox1.Text = Empty Then
      TextBox1.SetFocus
  Else    
       If TextBox2.Text = Empty Then .........
```

Imagine this with 34 nesting?
So I tried the `For Each` loop solution. But it's not working! Any idea?

```
Sub ValidarForm5()
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctrl.Text = Empty Then
                ctrl.SetFocus
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: "*But it's not working!*" is a bad error description. Is there an error? If so which and where? If not what does your code instead of what you expect? I think your code selects the last empty box instead. To select the first one simply add a `Exit For` right after `ctrl.SetFocus`.

Comment: Does an `Exit For` after the `ctrl.SetFocus` work?

Comment: Does `ctrl.Text = Empty` really work? I expect `ctrl.Text` to be a string which should be tested like `ctrl.Text = ""`, unless `Empty` is a variable itself, possibly undeclared, and happens to contain a null string.

Comment: Thank you, @Peh. Nothing happens! This is 2013 Excel!

Comment: Empty or "", is the same. Nothing happens!

Comment: Your `SetFocus` instruction may not work because of how you call the sub. F.i. if you call the sub with the on_click event the latter will be executed after the focus has been set and you never get to see that it actually ever was set. `Empty` and null string are two very different animals.

Comment: Thank you. I love that: "Empty and null string are two very different animals."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using your code within the UserForm itself use `Me` instead of `UserForm1` and declare your variables. If found an empty TextBox you have to Exit the `For` Loop, otherwise you won't remain in it.

**Code in UserForm**

```
Option Explicit    ' declaration head of your userform code module

Sub ValidateForm()
Dim ctrl As Object
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
        If ctrl.Text = Empty Then
            ctrl.SetFocus
            Exit For    ' escape to remain in found textbox
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ValidarForm5` code works. I've tested it on a Userform without throwing any errors. @Peh has provided an solution in his comment but I thought I'd expand by explaining what your code is doing now.

You are looping through all 34 textboxes, one at a time. So you're testing `TextBox1` to see if it is empty. If it is, then you `SetFocus` to that `Textbox1`. Then you move to `TextBox2` and test that. If it's empty, then you `SetFocus` to that `Textbox2`.. and on.. and on..

So this means that if the last TextBox (`Textbox34`) is empty, then that will be the last one that has focus set to it. If that isn't empty, then it'll be the one before, etc.. etc..

What you're after though, is the ***first*** `Textbox` that is empty. As @Peh mentions, you just need to drop out of your loop once the first one is set. This is easily done with `Exit For` like so:

```
Sub ValidarForm5()
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctrl.Text = Empty Then
                ctrl.SetFocus
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```